# Problemas con header C

Tags: c, headers

Tengo un código en C en el cuál agregué una cabecera "video.h". Para agregarla fui a Propiedades->Build->Linker->Add Library... y clic izquierdo en headers files->Add Existing item...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <video.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    VCA_VIDEO_HANDLE vvhd = NULL;
    vvhd = LIBVCA_VIDEO_init(VIDEO_IPC_AGENT_SERVER);

    _FRAME_INFO frameInfo;
    frameInfo.width = 720;
    frameInfo.height = 480;
    frameInfo.pitch = 736;
    frameInfo.format = VIDEO_FORMAT_YUV422_YU16;
    frameInfo.frameRate = 30;
    frameInfo.frameSize = 720 * 480 * 2;
    frameInfo.lumaSize = 720 * 480;
    frameInfo.chromaSize = 720 * 480;
    frameInfo.lumaAddrOffset = 0;
    frameInfo.chromaAddrOffset = 0;

    if (LIBVCA_VIDEO_setFrameInfo(vvhd, &frameInfo) < 0) {
        printf("Setup Frame Info fail\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Pero me sale este error.

```
cd
'C:\Users\sistemasnet6\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Camaras_sdk'
C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug "/usr/bin/make" -f
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf make[1]:
Entering directory
'/cygdrive/c/Users/sistemasnet6/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Camaras_sdk'
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk
dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/camaras_sdk.exe make[2]: Entering directory
'/cygdrive/c/Users/sistemasnet6/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Camaras_sdk'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows gcc -o
dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/camaras_sdk
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o -lvideo.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:
cannot find -lvideo.h collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:63:
dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/camaras_sdk.exe] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving
directory
'/cygdrive/c/Users/sistemasnet6/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Camaras_sdk'
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: .build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory
'/cygdrive/c/Users/sistemasnet6/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Camaras_sdk'
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:40: .build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 857ms)
```

Comment: La verdad que desconozco los parámetros de make.exe, pero me llama la atención que diga que no encuentra `-lvideo.h`, como si lo buscara con guion y `l` inicial.

Comment: a simple vista, tienes un `r` de mas antes del `return 0;`.

Comment: perdón, la "r" fue error al escribir la pregunta, en el código no está y aún así me sale ese error..

Comment: `video.h` es un header. "Add library" no funciona con headers. Headers no son bibliotecas. Nesecitas añadir una biblioteca allí.

Comment: La opción `-l` especifica el nombre de la biblioteca, pero `video.h` no es una biblioteca, es inválido hacer esto: `-lvideo.h`.